# How can I install slowaes for Python on Mac?

Tags: python

When attempting to install the Electrum Bitcoin client, I get the following error:

```
Downloading/unpacking slowaes (from Electrum==1.8.1)
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement slowaes (from Electrum==1.8.1)    (from versions: 0.1a1)
```

Does anyone know how I can potentially get around this error / install slowaes on Mac?

Comment: if its only `slowaes` thats making problems, try doing `pip install slowaes` and then rerunning the Electrum installation

Comment: @tttthomasssss Thanks for commenting!  Just tried that, and got the same error ("Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement slowaes (from versions: 0.1a1)").  Any ideas on additional troubleshooting steps?

Comment: how did you try to install it? `sudo pip install https://download.electrum.org/Electrum-1.9.8.tar.gz#md5=e3918fec0254267f08e41a1fb8691382` (see https://electrum.org/download.html; its the Linux option, but I'm on OS X as well) worked for me.

Comment: @tttthomasssss Just tried that, got the same error.  Which version of OSX are you on?  (Thanks again for the help here, by the way!)

Comment: I'm still on Mountain Lion, have you tried installing Electrum into a fresh `virtualenv`?